# Efficient way of painting HTML Canvas image by pixels using Blazor (client side)

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor-client-side

Currently I simple have a C# class that represents a color, something like that:

```
public class Color
{
        public double Red { get; }
        public double Green { get; }
        public double Blue { get; }

        public Color(double red, double green, double blue)
        {
            Red = red;
            Green = green;
            Blue = blue;
        }
}
```

And a javascript method to paint an image:

```
window.canvas = {
    render: (canvas, width, height, colors) => {
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;

        let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        let imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        let data = imageData.data;

        let length = width * height;
        for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            let dataIndex = i * 4;
            data[dataIndex] = colors[i].red;
            data[dataIndex + 1] = colors[i].green;
            data[dataIndex + 2] = colors[i].blue;
            data[dataIndex + 3] = 255;
        }

        context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

I call that method from Blazor (where `data` is an array of `Color`):

```
await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("canvas.render", new object[] { CanvasElement, canvas.Width, canvas.Height, data });
```

I am generating an image programmatically using C#, with dimensions 900 x 550 = 495000 pixel colors.
I am albe to debug the javascript call with the web browser, and I can see that I have sent the parameters correctly. The image is rendered correctly too.
However, it takes several minutes to fill the javascript parameters from blazor.

Is it there any efficient way of painting a Canvas image pixel by pixel using Blazor (client side)?

Answer (score 1):

I am glad to know the way you tried in javascript is slow, because I was thinking of trying that.

I have a Nuget package called DataJuggler.PixelDatabase, and I am doing the same thing as you but in C# code, then I just save the image to a new file name.

https://github.com/DataJuggler/PixelDatabase

I am currently refactoring it now, because my first version was using 7 gigs of memory when I tried to hold a List with up to 20+ million items.

This class here does the same thing as your JavaScript. Someone posted it here years ago and I wish I had kept their info to give them credit.

```
#region using statements

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

#endregion

namespace DataJuggler.PixelDatabase
{

    #region class DirectBitmap
    /// <summary>
    /// This class is used as a faster alternative to GetPixel and SetPixel
    /// </summary>
    public class DirectBitmap : IDisposable
    {

        #region Constructor
        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new instance of a 'DirectBitmap' object.
        /// </summary>
        public DirectBitmap(int width, int height)
        {
            Width = width;
            Height = height;
            Bits = new Int32[width * height];
            BitsHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(Bits, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            Bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, width * 4, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb, BitsHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods

            #region Dispose()
            /// <summary>
            /// method Dispose
            /// </summary>
            public void Dispose()
            {
                if (Disposed) return;
                Disposed = true;
                Bitmap.Dispose();
                BitsHandle.Free();
            }
            #endregion

            #region GetPixel(int x, int y)
            /// <summary>
            /// method Get Pixel
            /// </summary>
            public Color GetPixel(int x, int y)
            {
                int index = x + (y * Width);
                int col = Bits[index];
                Color result = Color.FromArgb(col);

                return result;
            }
            #endregion

            #region SetPixel(int x, int y, Color color)
            /// <summary>
            /// method Set Pixel
            /// </summary>
            public void SetPixel(int x, int y, Color color)
            {
                int index = x + (y * Width);
                int col = color.ToArgb();

                Bits[index] = col;
            }
            #endregion

        #endregion

        #region Properties

            #region Bitmap
            /// <summary>
            /// method [Enter Method Description]
            /// </summary>
            public Bitmap Bitmap { get; private set; }
            #endregion

            #region Bits
            /// <summary>
            /// method [Enter Method Description]
            /// </summary>
            public Int32[] Bits { get; private set; }
            #endregion

            #region BitsHandle
            /// <summary>
            /// This is a ptr to the garbage collector
            /// </summary>
            protected GCHandle BitsHandle { get; private set; }
            #endregion

            #region Disposed
            /// <summary>
            /// method [Enter Method Description]
            /// </summary>
            public bool Disposed { get; private set; }
            #endregion

            #region Height
            /// <summary>
            /// method [Enter Method Description]
            /// </summary>
            public int Height { get; private set; }
            #endregion

            #region Width
            /// <summary>
            /// method [Enter Method Description]
            /// </summary>
            public int Width { get; private set; }
            #endregion

        #endregion

    }
    #endregion

}
```

Then this class here has an example of how to load the DirectBitmap.
Some of this is specific to my app, but you can take out what you need.

```
#region using statements

using DataJuggler.UltimateHelper.Core;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

#endregion

namespace DataJuggler.PixelDatabase
{

    #region class PixelDatabaseLoader
    /// <summary>
    /// This class is used to load PixelDatabases and their DirectBitmaps
    /// </summary>
    public class PixelDatabaseLoader
    {

        #region Methods

            #region LoadPixelDatabase(Image original, StatusUpdate updateCallback)
            /// <summary>
            /// This method is used to load a PixelDatabase and its DirectBitmap object.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="bitmap"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public static PixelDatabase LoadPixelDatabase(Image original, StatusUpdate updateCallback)
            {
                // initial valule
                PixelDatabase pixelDatabase = null;

                try
                {
                    // convert to a bitmap
                    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) original;

                    pixelDatabase = LoadPixelDatabase(bitmap, updateCallback);
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    // write to console for now
                    DebugHelper.WriteDebugError("LoadPixelDatabase", "PixelDatabaseLoader", error);
                }
                finally
                {

                }

                // return value
                return pixelDatabase;
            }
            #endregion

            #region LoadPixelDatabase(string imagePath, StatusUpdate updateCallback)
            /// <summary>
            /// This method is used to load a PixelDatabase and its DirectBitmap object from an imagePath
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="bitmap"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public static PixelDatabase LoadPixelDatabase(string imagePath, StatusUpdate updateCallback)
            {
                // initial valule
                PixelDatabase pixelDatabase = null;

                try
                {
                    // if we have an imagePath
                    if (TextHelper.Exists(imagePath))
                    { 
                        // create the Bitmap
                        using (Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) Bitmap.FromFile(imagePath))
                        {
                            // load the pixelDatabase
                            pixelDatabase = LoadPixelDatabase(bitmap, updateCallback);
                        }
                    }   
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    // write to console for now
                    DebugHelper.WriteDebugError("LoadPixelDatabase", "PixelDatabaseLoader", error);
                }
                finally
                {

                }

                // return value
                return pixelDatabase;
            }
            #endregion

            #region LoadPixelDatabase(Bitmap original, StatusUpdate updateCallback)
            /// <summary>
            /// This method is used to load a PixelDatabase and its DirectBitmap object.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="bitmap"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public static PixelDatabase LoadPixelDatabase(Bitmap original, StatusUpdate updateCallback)
            {
                // initial valule
                PixelDatabase pixelDatabase = null;

                // locals
                int max = 0;

                try
                {
                    // if we have an image
                    if (NullHelper.Exists(original))
                    { 
                        // create a new bitmap
                        using (Bitmap source = new Bitmap(original))
                        {
                             // Create a new instance of a 'PixelDatabase' object.
                            pixelDatabase = new PixelDatabase();

                            // Create a DirectBitmap
                            pixelDatabase.DirectBitmap = new DirectBitmap(source.Width, source.Height);

                            // Code To Lockbits
                            BitmapData bitmapData = source.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, source.PixelFormat);
                            IntPtr pointer = bitmapData.Scan0;
                            int size = Math.Abs(bitmapData.Stride) * source.Height;
                            byte[] pixels = new byte[size];
                            Marshal.Copy(pointer, pixels, 0, size);

                            // End Code To Lockbits

                            // Marshal.Copy(pixels,0,pointer, size);
                            source.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

                            // locals
                            Color color = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
                            int red = 0;
                            int green = 0;
                            int blue = 0;
                            int alpha = 0;

                            // variables to hold height and width
                            int width = source.Width;
                            int height = source.Height;
                            int x = -1;
                            int y = 0;

                            // if the UpdateCallback exists
                            if (NullHelper.Exists(updateCallback))
                            {
                                // Set the value for max
                                max = height * width;    

                                // Set the graph max
                                updateCallback("SetGraphMax", max);
                            }

                            // Iterating the pixel array, every 4th byte is a new pixel, much faster than GetPixel
                            for (int a = 0; a < pixels.Length; a = a + 4)
                            {
                                // increment the value for x
                                x++;

                                // every new column
                                if (x >= width)
                                {
                                    // reset x
                                    x = 0;

                                    // Increment the value for y
                                    y++;
                                }      

                                // get the values for r, g, and blue
                                blue = pixels[a];
                                green = pixels[a + 1];
                                red = pixels[a + 2];
                                alpha = pixels[a + 3];

                                // create a color
                                color = Color.FromArgb(alpha, red, green, blue);

                                // Set the pixel at this spot
                                pixelDatabase.DirectBitmap.SetPixel(x, y, color);
                            }
                        }

                        // Create the MaskManager 
                        pixelDatabase.MaskManager = new MaskManager();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    // write to console for now
                    DebugHelper.WriteDebugError("LoadPixelDatabase", "PixelDatabaseLoader", error);
                }

                // return value
                return pixelDatabase;
            }
            #endregion

        #endregion

    }
    #endregion

}
```

So after I load my image and apply changes, I update save like this:

```
// get the bitmap
Bitmap bitmap = PixelDatabase.DirectBitmap.Bitmap;

// Get a fileInfo of the oldPath
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(FullImagePath);

// Get the index of the period
int index = fileInfo.Name.IndexOf(".");

// get the name
string name = fileInfo.Name.Substring(0, index);

// Get the directory
DirectoryInfo directory = fileInfo.Directory;

// get the directoryFullname
string fullPath = directory.FullName;

// newFileName
string newFileName = name + "." + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 12) + ".png";

// Get the newPath
string newPath = Path.Combine(fullPath, newFileName);

// Save
bitmap.Save(newPath, ImageFormat.Png);
```

This can load and save 20 meg images in a few seconds.

We should team up, sounds like we are working on the same thing. I am thinking of writing a Windows service that can update the files directly, and to remove the image processing from blazor.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response! It seems to work with Blazor Server side. However, I am using Blazor Client side, and it crashes when `DirectBitmap` tries to create a `new Bitmap`. I think also that I cannot generate a local file from Blazor Client side and show it in the web site. Whan I am trying to do is to show a procedurally generated image inside a canvas. Thank you again for the great post.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work for you. I have yet to try Blazor client side (Web Assembly). I have always been more of a server person.

I am building a Blazor site called PixelDatabase.Net, and I do query updates to images using a language called BQL, very similar to SQL, so it also does image updates.  Are you stuck on client side Blazor?

Comment: Thank you for commenting. My application is working correctly. The only issue I have is the performance, since transforming 495000 pixels color from Blazor (client side) to javascript seems to be extremelly slow. Your project looks great. It might be nice to have something like LINQ to BQL :)

Comment: Originally I loaded a List of PixelInformation objects, and you could use Linq. I just published a new version yesterday, that doesn't take up as much memory. I still use the PixelInformation object, but I just don't hold the objects in memory. Later today I hope to publish the site https://pixeldatabase.net. Thanks for the compliment. It is still a work in progress as I figure out the most efficient ways of doing things.

Comment: My site is live now if you want to check it out (sorry if anyone thinks this is spam. I worked on it for 6 weeks). https://pixeldatabase.net. It is blazing fast if that isn't too blazorious to say. Blazor is the best thing that ever happened to web developmen to me.

Comment: @user12228709 what does it do?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to generate an image formated as base64 PNG in client side, and assign it as an HTML img src attribute:

- With `DirectBitmap`: The application crashes when creating a `Bitmap`.
- With `SkiaSharp`: The application crashes when creating an `SKBitmap`.
- With `ImageSharp`: The application generates the image.

The code to generate the base64 image is (with ImageSharp):

```
public static string ToBase64Image(this Canvas canvas)
{
    string base64 = null;

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var image = new Image<Rgba32>(canvas.Width, canvas.Height))
        {
            for (var x = 0; x < canvas.Width; x++)
            {
                for (var y = 0; y < canvas.Height; y++)
                {
                    var c = image[1, 2];
                    image[x, y] = canvas[x, y].ToImageSharpColor();
                }
            }

            image.SaveAsPng(memoryStream);
            base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
    }

    return $"data:image/png;base64,{base64}";
}
```

The blazor component just contains:

```
<img src="@Base64Image" />
```

And the `Base64Image` property is filled with the `ToBase64Image` method.

Depending on the image generated I get the error:

> blazor.webassembly.js:1 Error: Garbage collector could not allocate
>   16384u bytes of memory for major heap section.

Curiosly, it seems it doesn't depend on the size of the image, but on the complexity of the image. Is it possible that exists any issue with the garbage collector in blazor client side applications that doesn't allow the code to work?

In any case it is always very slow.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is to eliminate Blazor and checking the speed. Like filling those pixels with odd-even dots, that's all.

Then pushing the data from Blazor, but still not using it.

My guess is you use reference type for your colors, meaning to get single color JS has to hop over array reference, then over your Color reference, and then finally it can grab the color value. I would suggest at least comparing current performance to approach with array of doubles (similar way the JS image is organized).

Secondly you are doing all this is a foreground, background worker and then swapping images would be as slow as current version, but at least UI wouldn't be frozen.